# li does not displayed inside ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/eRtP3/

i have menu, inside li, there is another ul, when clicking on the li that ul displayed. but this jquery is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#side-nav .sub-menu").click(function () {
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#side-nav ul ul").slideUp();
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
  })
})
```

html

```
<div id="side-nav">
  <ul>
    <li style="border-top: thin #eee solid;" class="sub-menu">
      <i class="fa fa-upload fa-lg"></i>Upload
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="~/Log/Index"><i class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></i>Log</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
  #side-nav ul ul {
display: none;
    }
  #side-nav li.active ul {
display: block;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a slight tweak to your code, but the other thing to remember when using jsfiddle and you're using jquery is to include the jquery framework library.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#side-nav .sub-menu").click(function () {
    // if secondary nav is not visible, slide down
    if (!$('> ul', this).is(":visible")) {
        $('> ul', this).slideDown();
    } else { // else, it is visible so slide up
        $('> ul', this).slideUp();
    }
})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<div id="side-nav">
    <ul>
        <li style="border-top: thin #eee solid;" class="sub-menu">
            <!--Use a another wrapper element for the tirgger part-->
            <span><i class="fa fa-upload fa-lg"></i>Upload</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="~/Log/Index"><i class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></i>Log</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#side-nav .sub-menu > span").click(function () {
        //slide down the target
        var $nxt = $(this).next().stop(true).slideDown();
        //slide up all other elements
        $("#side-nav ul ul").not($nxt).stop(true).slideUp();
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C4MMA/)

Comment: @Parvathiiiii instead of `.slideDown();` use `.slideToggle();` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C4MMA/2/

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace

```
$("#side-nav ul ul").slideUp();
```

by

```
$("#side-nav ul ul").slideToggle("slow");
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eRtP3/2/)

Comment: again clicking on the li the ul is not hiding

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you jquery code-

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#side-nav .sub-menu").click(function () {
       $("#side-nav ul ul").toggle('slow');
      })
    })
```